# How to execute python function as whole in VSCode (it splits and sends just the first line to an interpreter)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, execution

I'm getting used to VSCode in my daily Data Science remote workflow due to LiveShare feature.

So, upon executing functions it just executes the first line of code; if I mark the whole region then it does work, but it's cumbersome way of dealing with the issue.

I tried number of extensions, but none of them seem to solve the problem.

```py
def gini_normalized(test, pred):
    """Simple normalized Gini based on Scikit-Learn's roc_auc_score"""
    gini = lambda a, p: 2 * roc_auc_score(a, p) - 1
    return gini(test, pred)
```

Executing the beginning of the function results in error:

```
def gini_normalized(test, pred):...
  File "", line 1
    def gini_normalized(test, pred):
                                    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

There's a solution for PyCharm: Python Smart Execute - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11945-python-smart-execute. Also Atom's Hydrogen doesn't have such issue either.

Any ideas regarding VSCode?

Thanks!

Comment: read your source file as a string and dump on the Python console to see if there are funny characters in the text. `print(repr(open('foo.py').read()))`

Comment: Thanks for response, but I don't think it's relevant to the original post. It's a nature of VSCode Python interactive shell execution that I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on the VSCode DataScience features. Just to make sure that I'm understanding correctly. You would like the shift-enter command to send the entire function to the Interactive Window if you run it on the definition of the function?

If so, then yes, we don't currently support that. Shift-enter can run line by line or run a section of code that you manually highlight. If you want, you can use #%% lines in your code to put functions into code cells. Then when you are in a cell shift-enter will run that entire cell, might be the best current approach for you.

That smart execute does look interesting, if you would like to file that as a suggestion you can use our GitHub here to get it on our backlog to look at.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: Hi Ian, first of all thanks for response!

Second, yes, that's what I'm looking for. Writing #%% or marking the whole region line by line isn't as efficient as smart execute. Yup, I'll file a ticket right away.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could click the symbol before each line and turn it into > (the indented codes of the function was hidden now). Then if you select the whole line and the next line, shift+enter could run them together.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAvui.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think he means to fold a function with an arrow or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+[   Then select folded line and the next one and run them.